# Socket Connection with Sub context of URL

Tags: java

I used below code to read sub context news from bbc site,but it is throwing UnknownHostException.Any hints please.

```
try {
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("bbc.co.uk/news/");
            int port = 80;

            // This constructor will block until the connection succeeds
            Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("exception is"+e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  the JavaDoc on `InetAddress.getByName(...)`:

> Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name.

In `bbc.co.uk/news/` the host is `bbc.co.uk` with `news` being a subcontext as you already stated.

So change that to `InetAddress.getByName("bbc.co.uk")` or alternatively use the `URL` class, if you don't have to use a `Socket` : `new URL("http://bbc.co.uk/news/").openStream()`.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.I have to do without help of URL package.

Comment: :I have to use only Sockets not URL package.

Answer (score 1):

Your [InetAddress.getByName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) method is incorrect. It should specify only the host name.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("bbc.co.uk");
```